# My code is not comparing two different strings correctly

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, object

I am attempting to solve this codewars problem:

> Complete the function scramble(str1, str2) that returns true if a
> portion of str1 characters can be rearranged to match str2, otherwise
> returns false.
>
> examples:

```
 scramble('rkqodlw', 'world') ==> True
 scramble('cedewaraaossoqqyt', 'codewars') ==> True 
 scramble('katas', 'steak') ==> False
```

This is my attempt:

```
function scramble(str1, str2) {
  let obj1 = {};
  let obj2 = {};
  for (el of str1) {
    obj1[el] = (obj1[el] || 0) + 1;
  }
  for (el of str2) {
    obj2[el] = (obj2[el] || 0) + 1;
  }
  for (el in obj2) {
    if (!(el in obj1)) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

I am converting the strings to objects, and then comparing the keys to each other. My code passes about 90% of all the tests on Codewars, but then it does not pass the other 10% and they do not show what the test inputs are unfortunately.

My hunch is that there are a few edge cases that this code is not catching. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the rules of replacement?  In other words, if I call `scramble("a","aa")` can the "a" get reused?  Are there any special rules for capitalization, or should capitals remain capitals and lowercase remain lowercase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the **amount of characters**. Now you just checking whether the character in `str2` also exists in `str1`.

So instead of:

```
 for (el in obj2) {
    if (!(el in obj1)) return false;
  }
```

Try:

```
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj2)) {
    if (obj1[key] === undefined || obj1[key] < value) return false;
  }
```

Which means that if `obj1[key]` doesn't exist or it has less occurrences than `obj2[key]` it will return **false**.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to handle the case when `str2` has more instances of a letter than `str1`.

For example:

```
scramble("a", "aa")
```

Which should evaluate to false (not enough 'a's in "a" to form "aa").

Answer (score 1):

this code maybe helps

```js
function scramble(str1, str2) {

    let occurences = str1.split("").reduce((arr, cur) => { arr[cur] ? arr[cur]++ : arr[cur] = 1; return arr; }, {});

    console.log(occurences);

    return str2.split("").every((character) => --occurences[character] >= 0);
}

console.log(scramble("awpoirwled", "world"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm I would use is to take each letter of the match string, and if its got an equivalent in the searched string, remove it from there and continue, otherwise abort if there is no match.
If you reach the end of the match string without aborting then you have a match